# Force fetched image data to https

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a solution to force images from a `fetch` **API** to be in `https` rather than `http`

The **API** returns image results as `http` from the fetched `JSON` file but this is giving warning in the console to `Mixed Content`

I am fetching in `componentDidMount` as

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    const proxyurl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const url = `//api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location/${this.props
      .tripAdvisorId}?key=${AuthKey}`;
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        self.setState({
          reviewData: data,
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }
```

and then `mapping` the **data** by way

```
{this.state.reviewData.reviews.map(i => {
  return (
    <div key={i.id}>
      <img src={i.rating_image_url} alt={i.title} />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

How can I force the `url` from `{i.rating_image_url}` to use `https` when this is not `returned` from the `fetch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a regular expression, something like:

```
{this.state.reviewData.reviews.map(i => {
      return (
        <div key={i.id}>
          <img src={i.rating_image_url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://')} alt={i.title} />
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = new URL(originalUrl);
url.protocol = url.protocol.replace('http', 'https');
console.log(url.href);
```

This method uses the built-in URL class to fully parse, and then uses a string replacement on the protocol.

Comment: Thank you Brad. I saw Anas answer first and this worked well but I before I accept their answer, I wondered if there are benefits to your solution or is it just another way of achieving a result? Cheers

Comment: @Darren The best benefit is if you pass a URL to be relative to as the second parameter.  For example, suppose your `originalUrl` is just `/something.html`.  That's not a full URL, has no protocol or anything so there's nothing to replace.  If you use `new URL(originalUrl, window.location.href)`, you will get a URL object back with the base domain, protocol, and the new path and everything.  It figures all that out for you, and then all you have to do is replace the protocol.  It's a more reliable method, but may not be necessary depending on the context of the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Brad, great explanation. I did quickly implement it into my code but because the data returned is not a single url I had to map the data here too, therefore I continued with the other solution. I do have another scenario where I will implement this. Thank you for your help and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code to check if you are receiving the image or not

```
<img src={i.rating_image_url ? i.rating_image_url : i.rating_image_url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://')} alt={i.title} />
```

This way we are checking if we are getting its value or not.

For more better understanding you can also do this

```
{this.state.reviewData.reviews.map(i => {
  console.log(i.rating_image_url);
  return (
    <div key={i.id}>
      <img src={i.rating_image_url} alt={i.title} />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

This will show whatever data you are receiving in rating_image_url on your browser console.

Hope it helps you.